# Is it possible to inspect the "computed" styles for ::after and ::before pseudo elements?

Tags: css, google-chrome, pseudo-element

Chrome shows me the `::after` and `::before` definitions (and inherited definitions etc..) in the **Matched CSS Rules** pane when I inspect an element. But the **Computed Styles** pane displays only the computed styles for the root element.

I have a whole CSS class hierarchy for the pseudo elements with some properties inherited and some overridden etc, and would like to know if there is any way I can see the set of styles that actually got applied (i.e. what the computed styles pane shows for the root element)

If anyone can shed any light on this, that'll be extremely helpful.

**Edit - 13th Feb, 2014**

Recent versions of Chrome indeed has this feature built-in Perhaps this little thread had something to do with them including it?? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`window.getComputedStyle( element[, pseudoElt] )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> `pseudoElt` Optional
>
> A string specifying the pseudo-element to match. Must be omitted (or null) for regular elements. Pseudo-classes can be specified like ":focus".

I'm possibly misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish, but here's some JavaScript to play with. I hope it's useful.

It iterates through every element in the document and attempts to get the `content` of its `:before`s and `:after`s.
If it finds any, it outputs the details to the `console`.
Simple, but demonstrable.

```js
document.querySelectorAll( "*" ).forEach( ( e ) => {
  const ebc = window.getComputedStyle( e, ":before" ).content,
        eac = window.getComputedStyle( e, ":after" ).content;
  if ( ebc || eac ) {
    console.log( e );
    console.log( ( ebc ? "Before content = " + ebc : "No :before content" ) );
    console.log( ( eac ? "After content = " + eac : "No :after content" ) );
  }
} );
```

```css
div:before {
  content: "This is a test.";
}
p:after {
  content: attr( data-content );
}
span:after {
  content: " dolor";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p data-content="&hellip;">Lorem <span>ipsum</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is although it's not all that obvious. If you are using Firebug you need to ensure that on the style drop-down tab you have "Only Show Applied Styles" selected. Then as you can see from the screenshot below, you should be able to select the pseudo elements and view their computed styling (or the styling that is applied) which takes into consideration any overrides etc.

[image: Computed styles]

Comment: Just realized you are using Chrome though so the answer is probably no.

Comment: I use both the browsers, even though chrome is what I use more. The problem is that i cannot 'select' the pseudo element in the browser since they aren't part of the DOM [and hence cannot be passed as arg to getComputedStyle()]. I can only select the root element to which i have attached the pseudo elements to. Anyways, thanks for the pointer.